# create guides in an After Effects comp window using extendscript

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I want to write a script that puts guides at a layer's current position in the comp window. I've looked through the AE Scripting Guide but can't find any reference to guides. It's the kind of thing that *should* be doable, but is it?

Comment: I don't know of any way to that with extendscript, because it's not object that have property and you can't read it's value. You can submit a [feature request](http://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html)

Comment: thanks, I did a feature request. I'm holding my breath…

Comment: You will have to wait for a long time on your feature. I seems like nobody is caring enough about the AE Scripting API. When they add new features to AE they update the API but it really takes them long. Maybe you can do a workaround with guide layers. Adding a shape layer as guide layer with some paths on it.

Comment: thanks Fabian, yes, that's the workaround I'm planning on using. I know what you're saying about Adobe neglecting the API; Adobe didn't even have to release documentation for the CC version because they it hasn't really changed from CS6. Lame.